How to configure Firebase Auth with Sign in with Apple for both Web and iOS apps using different identifiers?
I'm implementing Sign in with Apple for both a web app (Next.js) and an iOS app (Expo/React Native) using Firebase Authentication. The challenge is configuring Firebase Auth to work with different identifiers for web and iOS while using the same Firebase project.
Current setup:

Web App:

Services ID: com.example.app.web
Works correctly with Firebase Auth


iOS App:

Bundle ID: com.example.app
Uses Expo with Continuous Native Generation (CNG)


Apple Developer Configuration:

Both IDs are linked to the same primary App ID
Created a key for the Services ID and configured it in Firebase Auth


Firebase Auth Configuration:

Sign in method's service ID is set to com.example.app.web



The issue:

Web app works fine
iOS app authentication fails with:
FirebaseError: Firebase: The audience in ID Token [com.example.app] does not match the expected audience com.example.app.web



Attempted solutions:

Changed iOS Bundle ID to com.example.app.web:

Expected: Both apps would work with the same identifier
Result: App build fails, XCode error:
Failed Registering Bundle Identifier
The app identifier "com.example.app.web" cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.




Changed Firebase Auth service ID to com.example.app:

Expected: iOS app would work without changing its Bundle ID
Result:

iOS app: Works as expected
Web app: Fails with error:
invalid_request
Invalid client id or web redirect url.







I'm expecting to find a configuration that allows both the web app and iOS app to work with Sign in with Apple through Firebase Authentication, despite having different identifiers.
Additional context:

Web implementation follows Firebase and Apple guidelines
iOS implementation uses Expo AppleAuthentication
Both apps use Firebase JS SDK
Expo config (app.json) is properly set up for Apple login

Is there a way to configure Firebase Authentication to work with different identifiers for web (Services ID) and iOS (Bundle ID) apps when implementing Sign in with Apple? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
